# I implemented google admob sdk in unity 2018, I built in xcode 12.4, IOS 12 and it gives me these 3 errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I implemented google admob sdk in unity 2018, I built in xcode 12.4, IOS 12 and it gives me these 3 errors

[image]

Comment: You are missing a declaration for GADMaxWhatever. The compiler assumes the type is int to go on compiling. That triggers the other two errors. They go away if you supply the type declaration.

Comment: How can I do that? I’m not sure what I’m missing..thanks. Appreciate it